# Record confirmation email

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc, selenium-ide

Using Selenium IDE(HTML), I'm recording an registering under one website, and a confirmation email will be sent when the sign up is successful.

This confirmation message will be sent to my gmail. I was recording to check in my gmail using Selenium-Ide but I can't record.So I want to know how to record in gmail using selenium?

Comment: Well where is the email going? Gmail? Yahoo? Some other web page? How are you navigating to the email?

Answer (score 0):

Well where is the email going?

Gmail?

Yahoo?

Some other web page?

The above four questions is important! Because, let's say you want to check confirmation email to your `gmail` if so you need to go to `gmail url` and you need to record `Login and assert` things.

I will be show you a example with gmail.

I want to check in my gmail if so

command `open`
Target `https://mail.google.com/`

this one need to add to your test. Because of you need to go to new page so you need to use `open` command.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [PutsBox](http://putsbox.com). You can send an email to whatever-you-want@putsbox.com, wait for a few seconds (SMTP stuff ins't instantaneous) then check your email via http://preview.putsbox.com/p/whatever-you-want/last.

This [post tutorial](http://www.pablocantero.com/blog/2015/08/05/test-emails-with-automated-testing-tools/) shows some examples.